# Capped Geometric Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The Geometric Distribution is defined as the number of trials it takes for the first success to appear in a sequence of Bernoulli trials.

My question is what happens when the number of trials is capped at a number $N$? That is what would the distribution of $Y$ be if we define it as

$$Y = min(X, N) \quad X \sim Geom(p), \quad N \in \mathbb{N}$$

I found one [article](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-gazette/article/7353-a-truncated-geometric-distribution/D1DF6CD157C870199EDA1AD275B28F80) that references this type of problem (group of people playing a dice game, $Y$ determines the winner) but the main difference is that $Y$ gets reset to the support of $X$ and not set equal to $N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference in truncated and original geometric distribution is in "last value": $X$ can take values $1,2,\ldots$ and $Y$ can take values $1,2,\ldots, N$ only.  And $Y=N$ iff $X\geq N$, so
$$
\mathbb P(Y=N)=\mathbb P(X\geq N) = \mathbb P(N-1 \text{ unsuccesses})=(1-p)^{N-1}.
$$
All the other values of $Y$ have the same probabilities as for $X$: for $k=1,2,\ldots,N-1$,
$$
\mathbb P(Y=k)=\mathbb P(X=k) = p(1-p)^{k-1}.
$$